# Silverlight, Path.Width and Path.Height is NaN

Tags: silverlight, path, width

I'm begginer in Silverlight and
I have next code:

```
private void btnAdd_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string xmlns = "xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"";
    string xmlnsx = "xmlns:x=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml\"";
    string pathXaml =
        String.Format("<Path {0} {1} Data=\"{2}\" />", xmlns, xmlnsx,this.Resources[txt.Text].ToString());
    Path p1 = (Path)System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(pathXaml);

    //p1.Width == NaN ?????? 
}
```

Can somebody explain to me why p1.Width is NaN?

Thanks,
Viktor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Path inherits from FrameworkElement and there the default value is set to Double.NaN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.width(v=vs.95).aspx). If you want to get the current width, use the ActualWidth Property of the path. This is the width of the currently rendered Path.

BR,

TJ